# Why this is not working? Null pointer in Android

Tags: android

check the below code and help me out lads. I don't know where I'm doing anything wrong. please check and help me

```
WebView wv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); // here is the error. What is wrong in this line?

            wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

            loadTime(); // execution is not coming till this part.
        }
```

// execution is not coming till here, crashing at findViewByID

```
        public void loadTime()
        {
            String page = "<html> <body> <a href = 'hi'>" + DateUtils.formatDateTime(this
                    , new Date().getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME) +
                    "</a></body></html>";

            wv.loadData(page, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }


        private class Callback extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView w, String s)
            {
                loadTime();

                return true;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Whenever I try to execute it, giving null pointer on webview. I don't know how to solve this, please helppp, really thanks

Comment: write this line `setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);` before this line `wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);` and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `setContentView(R.layout.main)` before writing the `findViewByID`. For activity you should call `setContentView()` before initialising the ids.

Answer (score 3):

In an activity you need to call `setContentView()` first to set a layout. Only after that can you find anything from it with `findViewById()`. Make sure you actually set a content view that contains a view with the id you're trying to find, too.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not using setContentView, and without contentView you're not calling your XML and that's the reason you're getting NPE. Try the code below:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); // here is the error. What is wrong in this line?

    wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

    loadTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()`, Need to call `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutxmlname);` before

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

So that the WebView can be identified.

The Null Pointer exception is being thrown as compiler does not know where to look for the `WebView`, in which layout, for your activity.

Please go through the following before programming any further:

1. [Android programming setcontentview](http://bloggerinme.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/android-programming-setcontentview/)
2. [Activity, its lifecycle and other details - android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)